# How to select id object in json data and add to another json data object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want select one object in json data(productData) and add to another object array(saveProduct) in json data(storeData),,,

productData component  :////////////

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { dragSource, DragSource } from 'react-dnd'

const itemSource = {
beginDrag(element) {
return element.item
},
endDrag(element, monitor, component) {
if (!monitor.didDrop()) {
  return
}
return element.handleDrop(element.item.id),
console.log("Return id",element.item.id)
}
}
function collect (connect, monitor) {
return {
connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview(),
isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}
}
class Products extends Component {
render () {
 const { isDragging, connectDragSource, item } = this.props
 const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1
 return connectDragSource(
  <div>
    <div className='item' style={{ opacity}}>
      {item.name}
    </div>
  </div>
  )
  }
  }
export default DragSource('item', itemSource, collect)(Products)
```

storeData component  : 
///////////

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { DropTarget } from 'react-dnd'

function collect (connect, monitor) {
return {
connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
hovered: monitor.isOver(),
item: monitor.getItem()
}
}
class Store extends Component {
render () {
const { connectDropTarget, hovered, item } = this.props
const backcgroundColor = hovered ? 'lightgreen' : ''
return connectDropTarget(
  <div>
    <div className='Store' style={{ background: backcgroundColor }} onClick= 
      {this.props.handleSelect}>
      {this.props.itemS.name}
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
}
export default DropTarget('item', {}, collect)(Store)
```

productData json:

```
[
{
    "code": "P1",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "product-no-1",
    "size": 20,
    "temperature": -18,
    "humidity": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 11
    }
},
{
    "code": "P1",
    "id": "2",
    "name": "product-no-2",
    "size": 20,
    "temperature": -18,
    "humidity": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 11
    }
},
]
```

storeData json:

```
[
{
    "code": "f1",
    "name": "storage-no-1",
    "capacity": 125,
    "temperture": -18,
    "humidity": 3,
    "saveProduct":[]
},
{
    "code": "f2",
    "name": "storage-no-2",
    "capacity": 15,
    "temperture": -18,
    "humidity": 25,
    "saveProduct":[]
}
]
```

I asked this question a few times and did not receive a response. Please help me.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @holydragon  productData id adding to saveProduct array in storedData

Comment: What's the relationship or condition to add? Or add it like n x n?

Comment: I think the ```forEach``` should be a ```map``` function to return values

Comment: @holydragon i'm use addItem function code , please check addItem function,,

Comment: @holydragon i'm want delete product select and add to saveProduct array,, function addItem deleted product select but does not add.

Comment: How to know that this product id go to which store data object in the array?

Comment: @holydragon My problem is exactly here, we want to add n products in the warehouse by drag and drop, each Store have array to save product

Comment: You should clarify this condition so people can fix this for you.

Comment: @holydragon We chose an object using the find method,
We must store this object in another array(saveProduct), Each of Jason storeData objects we choose

Comment: so you mean every storeDate will add the selected product into its saveProduct array?

Comment: @holydragon Yes i want this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187327/discussion-between-dani-and-holydragon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` to find the desired product by id. Than map through on the storeItems and find which one was the drop target (based on code I suppose). Then add the fount item to its saveProduct array using spread.

```js
addItem = (productId, targetCode) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const { productData, storeData } = prevState;
    const product = productData.find(product => product.id === productId);

    if (!product) return null;

    return {
      storeData: storeData.map(storeItem => {
        if (storeItem.code === targetCode) {
          return {
            ...storeItem,
            saveProduct: [...storeItem.saveProduct, product]
          }
        }
        return storeItem;
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I want to store each of these objects by drag and drop in saveProduct array

Comment: We chose an object using the find method, We must store this object in another array(saveProduct), Each of Jason storeData objects we choose

Comment: Can you pls describe how can I select which `storeData` object should I put the product? Or it will go in every `storeData` item's `saveProduct`?

Comment: we have two json data  one productData(Product list) and the other storeData(store list), Now we want by drag and drop add products to json storeData that place of store this products named  saveProduct(array object), we want to drop product on any of these storeData objects save to saveproducts arraye same place

Comment: I edited my solution. Assuming on dropping you get a target id or code from where you have dropped the item. You need to pass both the productId and target code to this function.

Comment: hi, targetCode is undefined ,:(

Comment: Yes, you should give it a value on dropping. Pass the `code` prop of the targetted store data item ('f1', 'f2'...) to the `addItem` function when you drop the product onto it.

Comment: Where do you call the `addItem` function?

Comment: calling to productData component , just pass id product , I do not know how and how pass code in storeData

Comment: also add productData in question

Comment: in `handleDrop` can't you resolve the id of the target where the item has been dropped in?

Comment: What's your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187382/discussion-between-gazdagergo-and-dani).

Comment: Hi, I set the index target correctly, but this answer 
Does not run.

Comment: the target code should be `f2`, `f3` etc... which is kind of the id of the storeData

Comment: come back to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187382/discussion-between-gazdagergo-and-dani)

Comment: hi,please check chatroom

Answer (score 0):

Try this let me know if it is working for you or not

```
addItem=(id)=>{
        const productData  = assign your productData json
        const savedProductData  =assign your storeData json:
        cobst productToBeAdded= productData.find(item => item.id === id);
        let saveProduct= savedProductData.find(item => item.code === productToBeAdded.code);
        if(productToBeAdded && saveProduct){
      if(!saveProduct.find(item => item.id === productToBeAdded.id)){
          saveProduct.push(productToBeAdded)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i'm want delete product select and add to saveProduct array,, function addItem deleted product select but does not add.